# Java negative int to hex and back fails

Tags: java, parsing, decimal, hex, signed

```
public class Main3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer min = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        String minHex = Integer.toHexString(Integer.MIN_VALUE);

        System.out.println(min + " " + minHex);
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(minHex, 16));
    }
}
```

Gives

```
-2147483648 80000000
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "80000000"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:459)
    at Main3.main(Main3.java:7)
```

Whats up?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's documented that `Integer.toHexString` returns a string representation of the integer as an unsigned value - while `Integer.parseInt` takes a signed int.  If you use `Integer.toString(value, 16)` instead you'll get what you want.

Comment: it would have been cool if there was a method to convert from hex to int/long just placing bits without caring about sign. That way it would have been possible to convert back and forth with minimal overhead.

Answer (score 13):

This is something that's always annoyed me.  If you initialize an int with a hex literal, you can use the full range of positive values up to `0xFFFFFF`; anything larger than `0x7FFFFF` will really be a negative value.  This is very handy for bit masking and other operations where you only care about the *locations* of the bits, not their meanings.

But if you use Integer.parseInt() to convert a string to an integer, anything larger than `"0x7FFFFFFF"` is treated as an error.  There's probably a good reason why they did it that way, but it's still frustrating.

The simplest workaround is to use Long.parseLong() instead, then cast the result to int.

```
int n = (int)Long.parseLong(s, 16);
```

Of course, you should only do that if you're sure the number is going to be in the range `Integer.MIN_VALUE..Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Answer (score 6):

According the the documentation, [`toHexString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString%28int%29) returns *"a string representation of the integer argument as an **unsigned** integer in base 16. "*

So the correct reverse operation is probably [`Integer.parseUnsignedInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseUnsignedInt-java.lang.String-int-) that was introduced as part of Java 8:

```
public class Main3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer min = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        String minHex = Integer.toHexString(Integer.MIN_VALUE);

        System.out.println(min + " " + minHex);
        System.out.println(Integer.parseUnsignedInt(minHex, 16));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public class Main3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer min = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        String minHex = Integer.toHexString(Integer.MIN_VALUE);

        System.out.println(min + " " + minHex);
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt( "-" + minHex, 16));
    }
```

}

to get this:

```
-2147483648 80000000
-2147483648
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to [include a negative](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) sign.

I don't have access to test this right now but I'd bet if you tried this value instead:

```
Integer min = Integer.MIN_VALUE + 1;
```

It wouldn't bomb, but would give you a positive number (not negative) when you ran `ParseInt(min,16)`.

A *string* of bits doesn't really have enough info to determine sign in this context so you need to provide it. (consider the case where you use `min = "F"`. Is that +/-F? If you converted it to bits and saw 1111, *and* you knew it was a byte, you might conclude that it's negative, but that's a lot of ifs.

Answer (score 0):

This seem to work for me :

```
public class Main3 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer min = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    String minHex = Integer.toHexString(Integer.MIN_VALUE);

    System.out.println(min + " " + minHex);
    System.out.println((int)Long.parseLong(minHex, 16));
}
}
```

The integer is parsed as a "signed long" that handle such big positive number and then the sign is found back by casting it to "int".

Answer (score 0):

`Integer.parseInt()` takes in a signed integer as it's input. This means the input has to be between "7FFFFFFF" and "-80000000". Note the negative sign before "80000000". What you want is `Integer.parseInt("-80000000", 16)`. If you use 80000000 without the minus sign Java will interpret that as a positive number and throw an exception because the max positive integer for an int is 0x7FFFFFFF.