# Save Android color as int notation

Tags: android, colors

I wand to Theme a app in the same Color like my CM Theme and the App only allow to use a color picker,after looking in the shard preference of the app i found something. That's the Story but not the question.

This is what i found:

```
<int name="color_main_window" value="-13162859" />
```

My question is how i can generate this int from rgb/hex and the absolutely needed way from rgb/hex to int ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022364/how-to-convert-rgb-color-to-int-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `int` is a 32-bit signed integer. So, -13161859 = 0xFF372695. A color will be represented as an ARGB int, so

```
a = FF
r = 37
g = 26
b = 95
```

The [Color](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html) class has utility methods that can convert int to rgb or argb and vice versa.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005424/java-converting-int-to-hex-and-back-again