# Converting Hex in Java, wrong value with negative values

Tags: java, hex, decimal

I have seen several questions on the topic mentioned in the subject (e.g [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005424/java-converting-int-to-hex-and-back-again)), but it seems to me that none of them provided this example. I'm using Java7 and I want to convert a `String` representing an hexadecimal or a decimal into an `Integer` or `Long` value (depends on what it represents) and I do the following:

```
public Number getIntegerOrLong(String num) {
    try {
        return Integer.decode(num);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nf1) {
        final long decodedLong = Long.decode(num);
        if ((int) decodedLong == decodedLong) {//used in Java8 java.util.Math.toIntExact()
            return (int) decodedLong;
        }
        return decodedLong;
    }
}
```

When I use a String representing a decimal number everything is ok, the problem are arising with negative hexadecimals

Now, If I do:

```
String hex = "0x"+Integer.toHexString(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
Object number = getIntegerOrLong(hex);
assertTrue(number instanceof Integer):
```

fails, because it returns a `Long`. Same for other negative integer values.

Moreover, when I use `Long.MIN_VALUE` like in the following:

```
String hex = "0x"+Integer.toHexString(Long.MIN_VALUE);
Object number = getIntegerOrLong(hex);
assertTrue(number instanceof Long):
```

fails, because of `NumberFormatException` with message:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "8000000000000000"
```

I also tried with other random `Long` values (so within the Long.MIN_VALUE and Long.MAX_VALUE, and it fails as well when I have negative numbers. E.g.

the `String` with the hexadecimal `0xc0f1a47ba0c04d89` for the `Long` number `-4,543,669,698,155,229,815` returns:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "c0f1a47ba0c04d89"
```

How can I fix the script to obtain the desired behavior?

Comment: @Aaron, sorry, bad typing. I do `"0x"+Integer.toHexString(Integer.MIN_VALUE)`. Is this bad also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Long.decode` and `Integer.decode` do not accept complemented values such as returned by `Integer.toHexString` : the sign should be represented as a leading `-` as described by the DecodableString grammars found in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#decode(java.lang.String)).

> The sequence of characters following an optional sign and/or radix specifier ("0x", "0X", "#", or leading zero) is parsed as by the Long.parseLong method with the indicated radix (10, 16, or 8). This sequence of characters must represent a positive value or a NumberFormatException will be thrown. The result is negated if first character of the specified String is the minus sign

If you can change the format of your input `String`, then produce it with `Integer.toString(value, 16)` rather than `Integer.toHexString(value)`.

If you can switch to Java 8, use [parseUnsignedInt/Long](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseUnsignedLong-java.lang.String-).

Comment: I cannot return BigInteger for backward compatibility. For the cast, I made a mistake in the example that I typed, actually I was doing `"0x"+Integer.toHexString(Integer.MIN_VALUE)` and `"0x"+Long.toHexString(Long.MIN_VALUE)`

Comment: I'm not sure of what you are suggesting exactly. For instance, if you do `Long.parseUnsignedLong(Long.toString(Long.MIN_VALUE, 16), 16)` you still get a n exception, i.e.  `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Illegal leading minus sign on unsigned string -8000000000000000`

Comment: I can confirm that `Long.parseUnsignedLong(Long.toHexString(Long.MIN_VALUE), 16)` works (as well as the `Integer` counterpart)

Comment: The leading sign should be conforming to the grammar described in [`Long/Int.decode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#decode(java.lang.String)) : for an hex representation, it could be `Signopt 0x HexDigits`, i.e. `-0x8000000000000000`