# java.lang.Integer.parseInt fails with hex strings hat use the highest bit

Tags: java, scala, number-formatting, numberformatexception

I was surprised that the following forward backward conversion from 32-bit ints to hex strings fails:

```
Integer.parseInt(-2028332484.toHexString, 16)
```

Gives:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "871a1a3c"
```

Obviously a workaround is

```
java.lang.Long.parseLong(-2028332484.toHexString, 16).toInt
```

But I wonder if there is not a better (and possibly more Scala'ish) solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been answered for Java already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845230/java-negative-int-to-hex-and-back-fails).

Unfortunately there is no additional treatment for that transformation in scala AFAIK.

Scala defines in `RichInt`:

```
def toHexString: String = java.lang.Integer.toHexString(self)
```

and in `StringLike`:

```
def toInt: Int         = java.lang.Integer.parseInt(toString)
```

apart from `import java.lang.{Long => JLong}` and using `JLong` I don't know a more scala-ish solution than yours.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I see that the symmetric counterpart of `parseInt(_, 16)` is indeed `toString(_, 16)`, and there is no counterpart for `toHexString`.