# Java convert 16 bits signed to 4 digits hex

Tags: java, android, hex

When dealing with signed int conversion to hex, only  `Integer.toString(value, 16)`  is useful

see [a post on subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845230/java-negative-int-to-hex-and-back-fails)
but I need to format with 4 hex digits (leading zeros for positive numbers and not 32bits/8chars for negatif numbers),

in C++ the right function is `IntToHex( value,4)`
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.SysUtils.IntToHex

But I didn't fiund the equivalent in Java (Android).

Comment: 4 hex digits would be the type short (16 bits) not Integer (32)

Comment: found it : int StepRef =-2;
        String SS = String.format("%08X",StepRef);
        String SS4 = SS.substring(SS.length() - 4);

Comment: Are you sure that's what you want to do. It's only converting "half" the number".

Comment: yes, I need only 16 bits wide ! it works like IntToHex( value,4)

Comment: Yeah but if for some reason in your code you "overflow" e.g 32766 = "0000", finding out where and why is likely to be painful.

Comment: IntToHex() is not C++. It is just a functions that comes with C++ Builder.

Comment: my int is 16 bits, coming from dspic 16 bits, it can't overflow

Answer (score 0):

Found it :

```
int StepRef =-2;
String SS = String.format("%08X",StepRef);
String SS4 = SS.substring(SS.length() - 4);
```